# Asp.net Core : What is Docker Profile in LaunchSettings.json?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, docker-compose

I have an Asp.net Core application and I see profile called Docker in LaunchSettings.json. What is the profile and when it will be used?

Comment: to launch your app in docker during development.

Comment: Does it used when I run the application using docker-compose?

Comment: no, it is not used with docker-compose